# How to implement a phonegap call back to javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have the following code perfectly working, except ... well for the call back !

```
- (void)readBarcode:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options 
{ 
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new]; 
    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_EAN13
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 1];

    [[super appViewController] presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES]; 
    [reader release]; 
} 

 (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;

    resultText.text = symbol.data;
    resultImage.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSString* retStr = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithFormat:@"%@({ code: '%@', image: '%@' });", 
                        resultText.text,resultImage.image];  

    [ webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:retStr ];  

    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

I then call the function from javascript :

```
        function getIt(){
            PhoneGap.exec("BarcodeReader.readBarcode", "myCallback");
        }
```

Problem is that I don't understand how to call the 'myCallBack' function from c# (admit i'm a total newbie)

Comment: you did not accept the previous answer which i believe is the same as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188581/how-to-implement-a-callback-with-phonegap

Comment: agreed, but the question was not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

Add property to header file ( [How To Add A Property In Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c) )

```
 -(NSString *) jsCallback;
```

Get the javascript callback method and set the property

```
- (void)readBarcode:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options 
{ 
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new]; 
    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    // New Property added !!!!
    NSString * jsCallback = [info objectAtIndex:0];

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_EAN13
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 1];

    [[super appViewController] presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES]; 
    [reader release]; 
}
```

Use the javascript callback method here

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;

    resultText.text = symbol.data;
    resultImage.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // create the string
    NSString* retStr = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithFormat:@"%@({ code: '%@', image: '%@' });", 
                            jsCallback,resultText.text,resultImage.image];  

    //execute
    [ webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:retStr ]; 

    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Please mark [the other answer I provided you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188581/how-to-implement-a-callback-with-phonegap) as correct also

Comment: Thanks aaron for the reply; i had put the return string in the 'imagePickerController' that's why it didn't work but now I get the callback called actually on the imagepicker when it's launched; i want it to be called after the image is captured.

Comment: so i want : 1. Launch the capture 2. get the callback. With your example callback comes before capture result.

Comment: move the code back to the method imagePickerController after the picker is dismissed

Comment: done, now i get a 'arguments not defined' error. Can you please paste a complete code ?

Comment: code has been added you need to create a property for the javascript callback... then use that property in the imagePickerController.

Comment: Perfect ! Did the job ! Thank you very much. (you made a typo 'info' should be 'arguments').

Comment: Quick update "myCallback" is never called back, any idea on that ?