# Redirect_uri_mismatch when contacting Google APIs with OAuth2

Tags: cordova, google-api, oauth-2.0, sencha-touch-2

I'm creating a mobile app using Sencha Touch and PhoneGap. I want to be able to allow users to log into the app using their Google credentials but am hitting a brick wall with the initial request with the following error:

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost did not match a registered URI.

My Google API account has the default 2 URIs registered (http://localhost and urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob).

I have tried both of these with no success.

The request I am sending contains the following query string params:

- response_type: 'code'
- client_id: <client id>
- redirect_uri: 'http://localhost'
- scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'

The basic process is:

- build URL as above
- open new browser window (using ChildBrowser PhoneGap plugin)
- navigate to the URL
- at this point the Google login page shows and allows me to put in credentials
- after Login tap i am taken to an error page containing the above error.

I am testing this in the iPhone simulator and on my iPhone with the same result in both. The application doesn't apear to run on the http://localhost url but on file:///var/mobile/Applications/<guid>/<app name>/www/index.html but there is no option to add this in the Google Console (..or is there? :) )

Does anyone have any suggestions about why this isn't working? I have little to no experience with using OAuth and Google's APIs so any little hints are more than welcome!

Thanks in advance

Stuart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to read this as the best starting point for [Google API with OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp), and in your case you need this: [OAuth2 for Devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices).

Probably you are using the wrong endpoint, to request for a **user code**, you need to use the following endpoint:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code
```

This is an example using curl (in your case to authorize the access to the *Google+ API*):

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code -d "client_id=**your_client_id**" -d "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" -d "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
```

You'll get an answer like this:

```
{
  "device_code" : "4/AToZcyQ7U1BTV-xu4LAqpw02SgIW",
  "user_code" : "bqsj67hb",
  "verification_url" : "http://www.google.com/device",
  "expires_in" : 1800,
  "interval" : 5
}
```

Then you need to ask for authorization, showning the user the **user_code** and the **verification_url** to "pair" your app with the user account of the user. [Here there is a good example of this](http://www.tekgazet.com/android-phone-youtube-remote-control-computer/net/2272.html) or from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices#obtainingacode):

> After your application has shown the user the **user_code** and the **verification_url**, your application may begin polling a Google endpoint with the **device_code** that was returned with the **user_code** and **verification_url**. The URL of the endpoint to poll is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, and the interval between requests is specified as the interval in seconds.

The last step, ask for an access_token, using curl:

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "client_id=**your_client_id**&client_secret=**your_client_secret**&code=**the _device_code_obtained_before**&grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0"
```

you'll get an response like this:

```
{
  "access_token" : "y23r9.AHES6ZT78qJl14pTueruthfh5676TYDF234-Eme33iQ",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "id_token" :  "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiNzgyMTM3OTUzMjkwLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2iLCJ0b2tlbl9oYXNoIjoiUUt0YmxTZUdsRUdNOVdPcUliRGR2QSIsImlhdCI6MTMzNDE3MDI1NywiZXhwIjoxMzM0MTc0MTU3fQ.Iz_Sv9X2fCydj4VfEdDxwWVH70DEK-rSzA5pWV9bvBdYB5VwgwFd8CSnotesDzJxq5pSKGwnAgvBfxSUbuGVmdET3E2sbrLODKymO9FoBzenfVooCwRXurzxvjKWF1EL3007lOPzTx9UGjqwShjjKQRoNjLFs-OmGCJsZGTHTGE",
  "refresh_token" : "1/gjgpKUyppp223s43HMerTX-zS_2JUxQOCk"
}
```

and finally you can access the services you have granted (don't forget to configure the access from the API console, in your case the Google+ API)  with the **access_token** obtained.

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=y23r9.AHES6ZT78qJl14pTueruthfh5676TYDF234-Eme33iQ
```

---

Regarding the question of

> "The application doesn't apear to run on the http://localhost url".

The answer is **yes, this is the expected behavior**. This **redirect_uri** is telling you where to *callback* after successfully granted permissions to your app. In your case a mobile device.

In the case of *"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"*, is not exactly a redirect. You need to "catch" or "hook" this, to simply continue your process, maybe [this can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4188581/431841) or [this](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction).

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

My answer is not about a mobile app, but may be helpful for other people. I had a redirect_url_mismatch, and I fixed the problem by editing the redirect url in the  [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console#/project). The url has to match **exactly**, so that `http://localhost:8080` is not the same as `http://localhost:8080/`.

I was able to test it by opening [this link](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/&scope=https://www.google%5C%20apis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&access_type=offline) in the browser (substitute your `client_id`). If the `redirect_uri` is wrong, it complains; if it is right or you have already authorized access, it redirects to `localhost:8080`. Also, if you have already authorized access, it can be revoked [here](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens).

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea of checking the link in the address bar instead, fixed this much faster

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I did the following: registered my app in the API console as a Web Application instead of an Installed Application. Thus, I could register an http:// URL as the redirect uri. The body of the page of my redirect URL on a Apache server was:

```
<? header("Location:myapp://authorize?code=".$_GET['code']); ?>
```

With this, the app behaves actually the same as for other OAuth authorized services, such as facebook...